# einen Termin bei/mit jemandem

Tags: word-choice, preposition

- *Du hast einen Termin **bei/mit** der Leiterin der Personalabteilung.*

Which preposition is appropriate in this sentence?

Comment: Both are appropriate.

Comment: Is there any difference in meaning at all?

Comment: Very nuanced. Mostly, they are used interchangeably but "mit" refers a bit more strongly to the person whereas "bei" refers a bit more strongly to the location (their office, but they are present). With "bei" there would be a slightly stronger expectation that others might be present.

Comment: Vielen Dank! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are valid, but they have slightly different nuances in their meaning:

> Termin **bei** der Leiterin

This includes **mit**, but usually means that you go to her and meet at her office. **Bei** most times means, that there is someone else to come to the meeting except when you ask the other person directly like:

> Treffen wir uns **bei** Ihnen?

On the other hand:

> Termin **mit** der Leiterin

You meet her... it is not included where in this statement. This can be your office or her office or anywhere else and if you don't say anything in addition it is normally a personal meeting without anybody else.

Comment: Vielen Dank, Torsten! :)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Torsten's answer, there appears to be a slight semantic difference, too. Having an appointment "bei" someone implies that you come to them and it might also imply that you are not on the same level as them in some way. You don't have appointments "bei" peers, but with people who know more than you or have more power than you. An appointment "mit" implies more equality to me.